# Two internet connections, two routers, one network, IP address conflict

Tags: router, lan, dhcp, adsl

I have these configurations on two connected routers:

Connection = LAN to LAN.

- **ISP1**: ADSL internet connection 1.
- **ISP2**: ADSL internet connection 2.
- **DHCP**: `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.1.254`.

And this is how it is set up:

- **ISP1** -> Router 1 \ `192.168.1.1` (DHCP on) -> (Router 2 and DVR have static IPs By MAC Address)
- **ISP2** -> Router 2 \ `192.168.1.230` (DHCP off) -> DVR `192.168.1.239`

All devices are working perfectly on both routers, but the DVR keeps warning about IP address conflict, and **only** when I connect the two routers a mysterious device appears in Router 1 DHCP with multiple (75 clients) IP addresses.

Any ideas?

Router 1:

[image: Image.]

[image: Image.]

Comment: Why are `192.168.1.230` and `192.168.1.239` inside the range to allocate? Could you show a screenshot of this device with its 75 IPs?

Comment: Can you draw a network diagram? Anything will do, even a photo of a hand-drawn sketch.

Comment: Your DHCP scope overlaps with static IP adresses, so its only natural that you get a complaint about duplicate IP Addresses. Even though you set DHCP from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254, doesn't mean that ip addresses will be .2, .3, .4, .5. DHCP can also hand out .100, .200, etc. So its likely that DHCP hands out .230 and .239 and that the actual devices complain.

Comment: Will draw a diagram tomorrow. and I did try DHCP from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.229 but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed both routers' settings and it worked:

**Connection**: `LAN to LAN` (Router 1 Ethernet 4 to Router 2 Ethernet 4)

**ISP1**: ADSL internet connection 1.

**ISP2**: ADSL internet connection 2 + IPTV.

**Router 1**: `192.168.1.1`

**Router 2**: `192.168.2.1`

**DHCP2**: `192.168.2.2` to `192.168.2.254` Router 2 Ethernet 1 = `Desktop` & `Wi-Fi` = Default

**VLAN2**: `192.168.3.2` to `192.168.3.254` Router 2 Ethernet 2 = `IPTV`

**VLAN2**: `192.168.4.2` to `192.168.4.254` Router 2 Ethernet 3 = `DVR`

**VLAN2**: `192.168.5.2` to `192.168.5.254` Router 2 Ethernet 4 = `Router 1` = VLAN-DHCP Disabled

**DHCP Enabled**: Router 1 \ Router 2 \ VLAN2 Wi-Fi + Ethernet 1 + Ethernet 2 + Ethernet 3

**DHCP Disabled**: VLAN2 Ethernet 4.

**No more IP address conflict, plus:**

Wirelessly connecting to Router 1 gives access to ISP 1 by default.

Wirelessly connecting to Router 2 gives access to ISP 2 by default.

Wired access to Router 2 gives access to ISP 2 by default, or using this batch file script:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" dhcp
```

Wired access to Router 2 gives access to ISP 1 using this batch file script:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1

netsh interface ip set dns name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.1

netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" 8.8.8.8 index=2
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to provide a solution there needs to be a description of the goal.  Why are there two ISP connections?  In most cases the need for two ISPs is to provide load balancing and/or automatic fallback if one fails.  In this case both internet connections would be to a single router, then that router would provide the internet access to the LAN.

What concerns me is that in your image the WAN address is a local network address.  This is very unusual.  That can be a hint to a great many problems but not the one you describe, and not likely the kind that can be solved on a forum like this.

What can also be happening is a lack of precision in terminology.  What people often refer to a "router" or "modem" is actually more precisely a "terminal adapter".  A terminal adapter changes one network physical layer type into another.  This can get complicated real quick so I'm not sure how to explain the distinction easily.  What can happen with a terminal adapter is that you can see people on your network through the DSL line, people that are many miles away.

My advice is to contact a professional on this, someone that can actually touch the equipment.  Until then you should return things back to how the professionals set it up because you could be disrupting internet access for a lot of people.